givens / implicits for Scala 3 Union Types
I have some typeclass, e.g.:
trait ExampleTypeClass[A]
  // imagine one or more methods here

object ExampleTypeClass:
  given ExampleTypeClass[Int] = new ExampleTypeClass{/* ... */}
  given ExampleTypeClass[Boolean] = new ExampleTypeClass{/* ... */}

Furthermore, if I have instances of that typeclass for types A and B, I would know how to implement an instance for A | B (I am aware that A | B is equivalent as in =:= to B | A, but for my case, the order is irrelevant).
The most obvious way to implement something like that would be:
  given unionExampleTypeClass[A, B](
    using a: ExampleTypeClass[A],
    b: ExampleTypeClass[B]
  ): ExampleTypeClass[A | B] = 
    new ExampleTypeClass[A | B]{
      // imagine some logic that depends on a and b here
      // (which does not depend on the order of a and b)
    }

When implemented like that, I can call this explicitly - the following compiles fine:
val intOrBoolTC1: ExampleTypeClass[Int | Boolean] = 
  unionExampleTypeClass[Int, Boolean]

val intOrBoolTC2: ExampleTypeClass[Int | Boolean] = 
  unionExampleTypeClass[Boolean, Int]

However, implicit resolution fails:
val intOrBoolTC3 = summon[ExampleTypeClass[Int | Boolean]]
// results in:
//[error] Ambiguous given instances: both given instance given_ExampleTypeClass_Int in object ExampleTypeClass and given instance given_ExampleTypeClass_Boolean in object ExampleTypeClass match type ExampleTypeClass[A] of parameter x of method summon in object Predef
// [error] val intOrBoolTC3 = summon[ExampleTypeClass[Int | Boolean]]
// [error]                                                           ^    

Is there a way to make the combined implementation for A | B available in implicit scope so that summoning such instances would work?
I also tried some variants with inline and summonInline, but those did not solve the main problem which (as far as I understand) seems to be that both unionExampleTypeClass[Int, Boolean] and unionExampleTypeClass[Boolean, Int] return the desired type, leading to ambiguity.
I found a kind of related question Implicit conversion between a Union Type and Either in Scala 3, but besides confirming my suspicion what the root problem might be, I did not find an answer there.

I'd say: no. Not without some weird constructs which would prove that the types used in union have a least upper bound equal to Any/AnyRef/AbyVal. And without some way it's deciding how to combine them when A | B is the same as B | A so order of things in pattern matching is not obvious. I cannot think of a way of implementing this without a macro and without a lot of subjective assumptions how things should work.

In order to resolve ambiguity you can prioritize instances of type class:
trait LowPriorityExampleTypeClass:
  given ExampleTypeClass[Int] = null

object ExampleTypeClass extends LowPriorityExampleTypeClass:
  given ExampleTypeClass[Boolean] = null

or
trait LowPriorityExampleTypeClass:
  given ExampleTypeClass[Boolean] = null

object ExampleTypeClass extends LowPriorityExampleTypeClass:
  given ExampleTypeClass[Int] = null

You can try to use type class similar to shapeless.Lub ("least upper bound") in Scala 2 https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/shared/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeoperators.scala#L186-L202 Covariance between 3 types in Scala
trait Lub[-A, -B, Out]:
  def left(a: A): Out
  def right(b: B): Out
object Lub:
  given [T]: Lub[T, T, T] with
    def left(a: T): T = a
    def right(b: T): T = b

given unionExampleTypeClass[A, B, Out](using
  ExampleTypeClass[A],
  ExampleTypeClass[B],
  Lub[A, B, Out],
): ExampleTypeClass[Out] = null

But then not only summon[ExampleTypeClass[Int | Boolean]] will compile, also for example summon[ExampleTypeClass[Any]] will:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/680pTCXQQkqRxaXa2V6ldQ/5
If you want to forbid ExampleTypeClass[Any] etc. you can add constraints NotGiven[Out =:= Any], NotGiven[Out =:= AnyVal], NotGiven[Out =:= AnyRef]:
given unionExampleTypeClass[A, B, Out](using
  ExampleTypeClass[A],
  ExampleTypeClass[B],
  Lub[A, B, Out],
  NotGiven[Out =:= Any],
  NotGiven[Out =:= AnyVal],
  NotGiven[Out =:= AnyRef],
): ExampleTypeClass[Out] = null

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/680pTCXQQkqRxaXa2V6ldQ/8
But still an instance of type class will be defined not only for Int | Boolean. For example if you introduce an abstract type T >: Int | Boolean, summon[ExampleTypeClass[T]]  will compile too.

I also tried some variants with inline and summonInline, but those did not solve the main problem which (as far as I understand) seems to be that both unionExampleTypeClass[Int, Boolean] and unionExampleTypeClass[Boolean, Int] return the desired type, leading to ambiguity.

I guess the reason of ambiguity is different. If we don't prioritize the instances then both ExampleTypeClass[Int] and ExampleTypeClass[Boolean] are eligible candidates for a: ExampleTypeClass[A] in given unionExampleTypeClass[A, B]. If we prioritize the instances (like I did) then the higher-priority instance is eligible candidate both for a: ExampleTypeClass[A] and b: ExampleTypeClass[B] and given unionExampleTypeClass[A, B] produces an implicit of the type ExampleTypeClass[A | A] i.e. ExampleTypeClass[A] instead of ExampleTypeClass[A | B] with different A, B. It's difficult to express the logic "do not take the same implicit for the second time" without something like
given unionExampleTypeClass[A, B](using
  ExampleTypeClass[A],
  SecondBest[ExampleTypeClass[B]],
): ExampleTypeClass[A | B] = null

Finding the second matching implicit
(NotGiven[A =:= B] doesn't work because this constraint is checked after it's already inferred that A = B = higher-priority candidate i.e. when it's too late. We don't have A ≠ B on type-inference level like <:, we have it only on implicit-resolution level like =:=, <:<, NotGiven[... =:= ...], NotGiven[... <:< ...]. Actually, A ≠ B shouldn't be expressible because in DOT calculus every type is a segment [Lower, Upper] but A ≠ B is a union of two intervals rather than segments [Nothing, B), (B, Any].)

Try the macro
import scala.quoted.*

transparent inline given unionExampleTypeClass[X]: ExampleTypeClass[X] =
  ${unionExampleTypeClassImpl[X]}

def unionExampleTypeClassImpl[X: Type](using Quotes): Expr[ExampleTypeClass[X]] =
  import quotes.reflect.*
  TypeRepr.of[X] match
    case OrType(l, r) =>
      (l.asType, r.asType) match
        case ('[a], '[b]) =>
          (Expr.summon[ExampleTypeClass[a]], Expr.summon[ExampleTypeClass[b]]) match
            case (Some(aInst), Some(bInst)) =>
              '{
                val x = $aInst
                val y = $bInst
                new ExampleTypeClass[a | b] {}
              }.asExprOf[ExampleTypeClass[X]]


(I am aware that A | B is equivalent as in =:= to B | A, but for my case, the order is irrelevant).


both unionExampleTypeClass[Int, Boolean] and unionExampleTypeClass[Boolean, Int] return the desired type, leading to ambiguity.

Actually, the thing is not only in order. It's true that Either[A, B] =:= Either[Int, Boolean] means A =:= Int and B =:= Boolean. But A | B =:= Int | Boolean doesn't mean that A =:= Int and B =:= Boolean. It even doesn't follow that A =:= Int, B =:= Boolean or vice versa A =:= Boolean, B =:= Int. There is also an option: A =:= Int | Boolean and B =:= Nothing or vice versa A =:= Nothing and B =:= Int | Boolean. And moreover, A =:= Int | Boolean, B =:= T or vice versa A =:= T, B =:= Int | Boolean, where T is an arbitrary (maybe abstract) type such that T <: Int | Boolean.
When you consider A | B =:= Int | Boolean as a synonym for A =:= Int, B =:= Boolean this means that your logic is not ordinary logic with types (including union types A | B). Your logic is a macro logic where you consider A | B as an AST (actually, type tree). So it's not surprising that this logic can be expressed with a macro.

Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer, it's really appreciated. But though it is an interesting read, I'm afraid that for my use case, it sums up to "no, not possible". The precondition that the instance for A and B must be prioritized is not really acceptable for my case.

@MartinHH "The precondition that the instance for A and B must be prioritized is not really acceptable for my case." Why?

I'd want to make this available in a library mainly for the purpose of making developer's life simpler (think typeclass derivation). If devs need to consider implicit resolution priorities just for this "utility", it defeats the purpose of making life simpler. Imho, I'd rather accept that I need to call unionExampleTypeClass[A, B] explicitly (with explicit type parameters) than to restructure my code to ensure the implicits are prioritized to suit this mechanism.

For example: consider I have a type Encoding = "utf8" | "utf16" and I have given [A <: String : ValueOf]: ExampleTypeClass[A] = .... If I need to explicitly declare the instances for "utf8" and "utf16" and prioritize them, then that is a lot more explicit code than just creating the instance for Encoding explicitly.

@MartinHH I see. Since you'd like to make your library users' life easier then maybe you're ready to bear the costs. You can try a macro. See the update.

@MartinHH See also my remark about solving the equation A | B =:= Int | Boolean

thanks a lot once again. The macro-based solution is more or less what I was looking for, and your additional comments about A =:= Int | Boolean and ˚B =:= Nothinghelped me to understand some of the compiler errors that I saw while trying solutions withsummonInline`.
