Trying to work with Shapeless2 coproduct in Scala 3 (because of avro4s)
I need to work with Avro schemas in a Scala 3 project and I am having trouble with union types. Imagine a situation like this:
{
  "name": "ExampleObject",
  "namespace": "example.namespace"
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "location",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ExampleRecord",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "exampleField",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "int",
        "example.namespace.ExampleObject"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

The field 'exampleField' could be an int, a string or an ExampleObject. Now, both avro4s and avrohugger represent such fields using Shapeless and don't support Scala 3's union types yet. The outcome of avrohugger's class generation looks like this:
import shapeless.{:+:, CNil}

import ...

final caseclass ExampleRecord(
  exampleField: Int :+: String :+: example.namespace.ExampleObject)

Shapeless3 is unable to work with Shapeless2's coproduct, which is what both project use. I could manually transform the Coproduct in union types, but avro4s only works with Coproducts when it comes to serialization down the line.
I can cross compile Shapeless2 in my Scala 3 project:
("com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.10") cross CrossVersion.for3Use2_13,

The full scala-cli script is here on Github.
This resolves the import and compiles, but creating an object gives this compilation error:
final case class ExampleObject(location: String)

final case class ExampleRecord(
  exampleField: Int :+: String :+: ExampleObject :+: CNil)

object Main extends App:

  val myObject = ExampleObject("london")
  val myRecord = ExampleRecord(
    Coproduct[ExampleObject](myObject)   // <- error!
  )

Compiling project (Scala 3.4.2, JVM (22))
[error] ./scala3shapeless2.scala:42:39
[error] No given instance of type shapeless.ops.coproduct.Inject[ExampleObject, ExampleObject] was found for parameter inj of method apply in class MkCoproduct
[error]
[error] One of the following imports might make progress towards fixing the problem:
[error]
[error]   import shapeless.~?>.idKeyWitness
[error]   import shapeless.~?>.idValueWitness
[error]   import shapeless.~?>.witness
[error]
[error]     Coproduct[ExampleObject](myObject)
[error]                                       ^
Error compiling project (Scala 3.4.2, JVM (22))

How can I provide an instance of Inject ? The real problem is that I am not familiar with the workings of Shapeless and I can use any pointer about this 

It's not clear what the problem is. "both avro4s and avrohugger represent such fields using Shapeless" Why is that bad? "don't support Scala 3's union types yet." Coproduct can be transformed into union type. Reverse transformation can be tricky. "Shapeless3 is unable to work with Shapeless2's coproduct" Why should Shapeless 3 work with Coproducts? Coproducts can be defined in Scala 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483366 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74355212 Inject can be defined in Scala 3 via Scala 3 type classes or Scala 3 match types.

Union types and coproducts are not equivalent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78564453 For example Int | String, String | Int, Int | String | Nothing, (Int | Nothing) | String, Int | (String | Nothing) etc. are the same type but Int :+: String :+: CNil, String :+: Int :+: CNil, Int :+: String :+: Nothing :+: CNil, (Int :+: Nothing :+: CNil) :+: String :+: CNil, Int :+: (String :+: Nothing :+: CNil) :+: CNil etc. are all different types.

Thanks for your comments @DmytroMitin. I have added more context to my question, and also stated clearly what my problem is.

I'm afraid you'd have to use macros: union type cannot be unambiguously decomposed into components (A | B = B | A, etc, it's kinda untagged union) while shapeless.Coproduct assigns each type an index of sort (it's tagged union) , so it can be unambiguously decomposed into types (CNil and prepending). Normal methods of deriving things cannot handle adding arbitrary sorting of types in union, you'd have to use macro for that.

Thanks for your comment @MateuszKubuszok  Do you think there is a way to make Shapeless2's Coproduct work in a Scala 3 project? That's kind of where I am now.

Probably writing conversion ftrom Mirror.SumOf[A] into Generic[A] with transparent inline.

Well, your code
final case class ExampleObject(location: String)

final case class ExampleRecord(
  exampleField: Int :+: String :+: ExampleObject :+: CNil)

object Main extends App {

  val myObject = ExampleObject("london")
  val myRecord = ExampleRecord(
    Coproduct[ExampleObject](myObject)
  )
}

doesn't compile even in Scala 2 + Shapeless 2
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OlocTfi3TrGX1hBZrUNnDQ
type arguments [ExampleObject] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [C <: shapeless.Coproduct]

So it's not surprising that it doesn't compile in Scala 3 + Shapeless 2.
The type parameter of method Coproduct.apply must satisfy upper bound <: Coproduct
object Coproduct extends Dynamic {
  ...

  class MkCoproduct[C <: Coproduct] {
    def apply[T](t: T)(implicit inj: Inject[C, T]): C = inj(t) 
  }
  
  def apply[C <: Coproduct] = new MkCoproduct[C]

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/shared/src/main/scala/shapeless/coproduct.scala#L122C1-L132C1
If we fix this place then the code
import shapeless.{:+:, CNil, Coproduct}

final case class ExampleObject(location: String)

final case class ExampleRecord(
  exampleField: Int :+: String :+: ExampleObject :+: CNil)

val myObject = ExampleObject("london")

val myRecord = ExampleRecord(
  Coproduct[Int :+: String :+: ExampleObject :+: CNil](myObject)
) // ExampleRecord(Inr(Inr(Inl(ExampleObject(london)))))

will work both in Scala 2
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/KEHxOS02Q4iZFP1KN9pTvA
and in Scala 3
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/KEHxOS02Q4iZFP1KN9pTvA/1
Does this answer your question?
The type class Inject used in Coproduct.apply[...].apply[...](...) is not macro-based
  trait Inject[C <: Coproduct, I] extends Serializable {
    def apply(i: I): C
  }

  object Inject {
    def apply[C <: Coproduct, I](implicit inject: Inject[C, I]): Inject[C, I] = inject

    implicit def tlInject[H, T <: Coproduct, I](implicit tlInj : Inject[T, I]): Inject[H :+: T, I] = new Inject[H :+: T, I] {
      def apply(i: I): H :+: T = Inr(tlInj(i))
    }

    implicit def hdInject[H, HH <: H, T <: Coproduct]: Inject[H :+: T, HH] = new Inject[H :+: T, HH] {
      def apply(i: HH): H :+: T = Inl(i)
    }
  }

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/shared/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/coproduct.scala#L26-L43
You can see here ordinary Scala-2 implicits corresponding to Scala-3 given-using. So Scala-2 Inject should work in Scala 3 too.
But Scala 3 error message is confusing, indeed.
